# How to move hamburger menu icon to the right side of header?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I want to move my hamburger menu icon on the mobile to the right side of the screen. Currently it resides on the left. I have tried but couldn't find a way to move it to right. As I am not a CSS and HTML expert, I really need to do this but i am stuck. I am posting the html and CSS code below please have look. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
`/* Hamburger Menu */
/* Mixin */
/* reset */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #91cfa1;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* fade in checked menu */
}
nav .m-menu__checkbox {
  display: none;
}
nav label.m-menu__toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav .m-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 450px;
  width: calc(100vw - 30px);
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-450px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-450px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-450px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-450px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-450px, 0, 0);
  -moz-transition: transform 0.35s;
  -o-transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
nav .m-menu__overlay {
  background-color: rgba(103, 103, 103, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
nav .m-menu__header {
  padding: 0 16px;
  height: 50px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
nav .m-menu__header span {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
nav .m-menu .m-menu {
  -moz-transform: translate3d(480px, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(480px, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(480px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(480px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(480px, 0, 0);
}
nav .m-menu ul {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
nav .m-menu ul li a, nav .m-menu ul li label {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: 47px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  position: relative;
}
nav .m-menu ul li label.a-label__chevron::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-color: #333;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  right: 16px;
}
nav .m-menu ul li .-invisible {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
nav .m-menu .m-menu label.m-menu__toggle {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
nav .m-menu__checkbox:checked ~ .m-menu__overlay {
  display: block;
}
nav .m-menu__checkbox:checked ~ .m-menu {
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.wrapper {
  width: 480px;
  height: 667px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu" class="m-menu__checkbox">
    <label class="m-menu__toggle" for="menu">
      <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="arcs"><line x1="3" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line><line x1="3" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line><line x1="3" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line></svg>
    </label>
    <label class="m-menu__overlay" for="menu"></label>
  
    <div class="m-menu">
      <div class="m-menu__header">
        <label class="m-menu__toggle" for="menu">
          <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="arcs">
            <line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line>
            <line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line>
          </svg>
        </label>
        <span>MENU</span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li><label>Item 1</label></li>
        <li>
          <label class="a-label__chevron" for="item-2">Item 2</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="item-2" name="item-2" class="m-menu__checkbox">
          <div class="m-menu">
            <div class="m-menu__header">
              <label class="m-menu__toggle" for="item-2">
                <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="arcs">
                  <path d="M19 12H6M12 5l-7 7 7 7"/>
                </svg>
              </label>
              <span>Item 2</span>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li><label>Item 2.1</label></li>
              <li><label>Item 2.2</label></li>
              <li>
                <label class="a-label__chevron" for="item-2-3">Item 2.3</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-2-3" name="item-2" class="m-menu__checkbox">
                <div class="m-menu">
                  <div class="m-menu__header">
                    <label class="m-menu__toggle" for="item-2-3">
                      <svg width="35" height="35" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="arcs">
                        <path d="M19 12H6M12 5l-7 7 7 7"/>
                      </svg>
                    </label>
                    <span>Item 2.3 </span>
                  </div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><label>Item 2.3.1</label></li>
                    <li><label>Item 2.3.2</label></li>
                    <li><label>Item 2.3.3</label></li>
                    <li><label>Item 2.3.4</label></li>
                    <li><label>Item 2.3.5</label></li>
                  </ul>                
              </li>
              <li><label>Item 2.4</label></li>
              <li><label>Item 2.5</label></li>
              <li><label>Item 2.6</label></li>
              <li><label>Item 2.7</label></li>
              <li><label>Item 2.8</label></li>
              <li><label>Item 2.9</label></li>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><label>Item 3</label></li>
        <li><label>Item 4</label></li>
        <li><label>Item 5</label></li>
        <li><label>Item 6</label></li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: reset `right: 50px`to `left:50px;`? @ #menuToggle

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I have added the wrong code, please have a look on this updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Apply margin-left: auto to your m-menu__toggle class.

Comment: Hamburger menu moved to the right but online it still open from the right side.

Comment: Charles please respond....

Comment: If i apply margin-left: auto to m-menu__toggle class then hamburger menu moved to the right but on-click it still open from the left side.

Comment: Waiting for your response?

Comment: It depends on what effect you want. You will need to modify the positioning of the menu which is under your m-menu class. For example, instead of left: 0 you can remove this and make it right: 0. That will align it on the right side if that's what you want. At this point it's a matter for you to experiment to see how you want it placed.

Comment: How to make it fixed with vertical scroll auto.

Comment: If you want the mobile menu that open up to be fixed then you replace position: absolute with position: fixed in your m-menu class.